# How to display the word 'BahnhofstraÃe' unicodes in HTML page?

Tags: php, html

I having a the Word Bahnhofstraße But in html the word look like 'BahnhofstraÃe'  So How to Support the word in HTML.

Comment: google html special characters and you're done

Comment: Did You set proper HTML characters coding in meta tags?

Comment: Made a small overview of how to use [UTF-8 for PHP and MySQL](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).

Comment: here is [a SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) which is more extensive than martinstoeckli link about using UTF8 all the way through (the best way to avoid headaches in the future), and titles aren't in Comic Sans ^_^. Character encoding can be very tricky... oups, I see this was already flagged as duplicate to the exact same question...

Answer (score 1):

Check out: https://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html

So you end up with:
`Bahnhofstra&szlig;e` (`&szlig;`) or: `Bahnhofstra&#223;e` (`&#223;`) put that in your code and check it in your browser. See if that helps.

You can also check you `charset` forexample: `<meta charset="utf-8">` this can be set in the header. You can also set it with PHP.

Comment: Any Other Way to Support in HTML??

Comment: @RAMART Yes: learn about encodings and handle them correctly. See the duplicate.